# How to Center the Footnote mark and the Footnote

Tags: formatting, footnotes, typography

I would like to know if it is possible to center a footnote that contains a stanza of verse; for example, consider the following in which the footnote is indicated:

[image]

And the footnote is displayed at the bottom of the page as such:

[image]

I would like to do this in LateX.

Does anyone know how? (I am able to produce the asterisk instead of a numbered footnote, but I do not know how to display the stanza as shown.)

Any help you provide is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the `verse` package.

```
% centerfootnoteprob.tex  SE 569825

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{\begin{verse}[1in] 
  The poor ... \\ 
  with voice ... \end{verse}}

More text\footnote{Regular footnote with lots of words in it, maybe 
exceeding a single line of text.}

\end{document}
```

The optional length argument to the `verse` environment shifts the location of the verse's text. A smaller length shifts to the right. Adjust this according to the width of the verse's lines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That indeed does center the footnoted stanza. But is there a way for the footnote asterisk to be centered with the stanza as well?

Comment: @I.Chekhov I don't know. Perhaps you need to ask another question about this.